# Impossible install Mac OSX, probably firmware damaged

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, efi, firmware

Yesterday evening I install update on my MacBook Unibody (Version 6,1; Late 2009). The update run on Mac OS X 10.8.5 consist in security update and new version of Safari and iTunes. The update is run with the option "Install and shutdown computer". After when I open MB the keyboard is gone mad: when i tap on "s" output the "ì" ecc. I tried reset PRAM and NVRAM, enter diagnostic mode, reset SMB but the keyboard at startup not respond and so it starts OSX, but I can't use OSX because keyboard doesn't work (it's like SHIFT and CMD were permanently pressed). I set DVD install like the startup disk. I inizialize disk and tried install MAC OSX, but the OS doesn't start and starts DVD. By terminal (on DVD install) keyboard doesn't work perfectly while a external keyboard work. At this point install Xubuntu that work greatly : keyboard response correctly. Should I reinstall firmware and SMB? Can I do this from terminal (on DVD install, only option for me)? It's EFI problem?

Comment: What a mess :(, do you have external start up osx ?

Comment: Finally I install ML but keyboard not work. With Apple DVD service results two keys stuck: shift and FN. Any solutions? I want reinstall EFI firmware and SMC but I don't find on Apple website.